# Some of my classes variables "un set" themselves

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a class that is normally defined in an xcdadmodeld. Version control on such is a PITA, so when I wanted to add some more minor variables, I simply added them; the first line already existed and is defined in the model, the second line is *not in the model*:

```
@property (nonatomic) float latitudeNorth;     //this is a sample, there are more
@property (nonatomic) float latitudeNorthEast;
```

In the .m, I have:

```
@dynamic latitudeNorth;
@dynamic latitudeNorthEast;
```

I have also tried:

```
@dynamic latitudeNorth;
@synthesize latitudeNorthEast;
```

I load the values into these floats from a JSON string...

```
self.latitudeNorth = [inDictionary[@"latitude_north"] floatValue];
self.latitudeNorthEast = [inDictionary[@"latitude_1"] floatValue];
```

If I examine the values, they are correct. Later I go back to examine these values...

```
if (inLatitude > self.latitudeNorth) return false;
coords[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitudeNorthEast, self.longitudeNorthEast);
```

When I look at the values in the debugger, self.latitudeNorth has a proper value, self.latitudeNorthEast is zero.

It *appears* that the instance has lost its value for the ivars that are not part of the model. However, I was under the impression that's fine. I suppose I'm missing something else - a straight-up declare perhaps?

Comment: float means your coordinates lose precision. Why aren't you using double?

Answer (score 0):

If your property is not an attribute in your Core Data model then it's possible that the value will be cleared when the object turns into a fault. Core Data can later fetch the object again from the store but then your property is empty as it is not part of the attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using dynamic.If you write dynamic properties then you have to write setters and getter methods for the properties.i think if you dont define your getter and setter properties compiler will result in crash or will give errors and do not compile.

Comment: Which is why I also tried @synthesize. Both compile, but neither seems to fix the problem. I can see the values being read into the fields fine, and then a bit later, they're zero.